# How to filter TCP RST only from kernel space?

Tags: linux, tcp, firewall

I developing a c-based application running on Linux.
This application send/receive TCP packet to/from an external embedded device.
I know that the linux kernel space might try to take control of the communication and can start sending RST (reset) packets evry time the application recevice a SYN-ACK.
I set the following rule:

- iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP

but this rule 'blocks' even the packet from my application.

How can I filter only the RST and RSK ACK coming from the kernel/OS?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This makes it sound like you're trying to write a piece of malware that fully implements a TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Hi, no this application is not a malware. It simply test the TCP protocol of the external device.